# How make a call to a function in views.py file in Django from ajax-html in template folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am working with Django. I want to make a call to a function in `views.py` of an apps from html file which is `template/app_name/login.html`.
This function is called for login validation.
my code snippet:
index.html :

```
<script >
  function subLogin()
  {
    var emailid = document.getElementById("emailid").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if(emailid != "" && password != "")
    {
      if(emailid.length >= 4)
      {
        if(password.length >= 8)
        {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/test/',
            data: {'emailid': emailid, 'password': password},
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
              //alert(json['success']);
              if(json['success'] == false)
              {
                if(json['email'] == false)
                  alert('The Email ID Provided is not correct!');
                else
                  alert('The Email ID & Password Provided Do Not Match!');
              }

def test(request):
logger.info("inside check password function....")
if (request.is_ajax()):
    emailid = request.POST['emailid']
    password = request.POST['password']
else:
    emailid = ''
    context = {'emailid':emailid}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

This is my test function sitting in myapp/views.py file.
But unable to make this call from ajax.

I think I need to rectify the call from ajax code.

Suppose my `views.py` has "`def test(request)`:" function.
So,I want to call this function from html file to this `test()` with email and password as post parameters.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with that? Probably you need to post the Python code too. Can you do a "manual" `POST` to `/test/`?

Comment: hi Michelem posted my python code...but unable to make call to this python function from html. Would you please help me how me make call from html to views function.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are just like any other request. That is, you need a URL pointing to a view that returns an HttpResponse.

Comment: @ Daniel -> would you send me sample url for calling a views/test() in django?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Surely you have already written URLs for your other views; this is *absolutely no different*.

Comment: Let me explain:
In the Url file I have added test.
http://127.0.0.1:8001/yota/test/  -> when making a POST request from Firefox POSTER add on then able to call test function in the views.py file.
But using the above mentioned ajax call, trying to call the test function but unable to call it.

here test function is inside "yota/views.py" and ajax  function is inside "yota/templates/yota/index.html". yota is my app name.

If it is clear then guide me.

Comment: But your Ajax is calling /test/, not /yota/test/.

Comment: -> Thanks for your cooperation.
But after changing the ajax calling to /yota/test/ still it's not firing the test function. Do I need any csrf related thing..?